# Laravel Carbon usage

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a query.So when i try get data from database,it show me null.

```
$heading = DB::table('heading')->where('heading.post_date',Carbon::today())->first();
```

Comment: You can either use `whereDate('heading.post_date', '2016-12-31')` or this `where('heading.post_date' , Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d'))` if you have format in 'Y-m-d' or replace your date format in format section

Comment: Well if you go through the docs over [here][1], Then you'll understand that what you're trying to do is syntactically incorrect. It's `Carbon::today()->isToday()` @Pradeep is right also you've to format the date in a proper format in order to get some response.


  [1]: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with "whereDate" method ?

For example:

```
$heading = DB::table('heading')->whereDate('heading.post_date', Carbon::today())->first();
```

You can find more documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries